# How to prove: $\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x_{i+1}-x_{i}| \geq \max_{i \in [k+1]}x_{i} - \min_{i \in [k+1]}x_{i}$?

Tags: inequality

How to prove:

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x_{i+1}-x_{i}| \geq \max_{i \in [k+1]}x_{i} - \min_{i \in [k+1]}x_{i}\quad ? $$

Is it even correct? I know how to prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x_{i+1}-x_{i}| \geq x_{k+1}- x_{1}$$ Note that $\forall x_{i}\geq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $1\leqslant a\lt b\leqslant k$. Then 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x_{i+1}-x_{i}| \geqslant\sum_{i=a}^{b-1}|x_{i+1}-x_{i}| \geqslant \left|\sum_{i=a}^{b-1}x_{i+1}-x_{i}\right|=\left| x_{b}-x_{a}\right|.
$$
This implies that for all $1\leqslant a,b\leqslant k$, 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x_{i+1}-x_{i}| \geqslant x_b-x_a.
$$
Can you conclude?

Comment: Hence, I can choose $x_{b}= max_{i∈[k+1]} x_{i}$, and $x_{a}= min_{i∈[k+1]} x_{i}$ because it's true for any $1\leq a,b\leq k$? But doesn't this imply that $b>a$ because of the summation in the first equation?

Comment: If $b<a$, then you can swap $a$ and $b$.